# How to *multiply* (for lack of a better term) two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 simple dataframes defined by:

```
persons = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob']
})
```

[image: DataFrame A]

and:

```
periods = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2019,2019,2020,2020],
    'semester': ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's2']
})
```

[image: DataFrame B]

How can I *multiply* (for a lack of a better term) the two dataframes so the result would be:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob'],
    'year': [2019,2019,2020,2020,2019,2019,2020,2020],
    'semester': ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's2', 's1', 's2', 's1', 's2']
})
```

[image]

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the super quick reply. I was mainly lacking the name of the operation to look for (cartesian product - cross join)

Comment: No problem, glad can help :) Happy coding ;)